# Symfony2 - Error with a form that create an association (Many to Many)

Tags: forms, symfony, many-to-many

I have 2 entities in a Many-To-Many association.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Clown
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Appuntamento", inversedBy="partecipanti")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="partecipa")
     */
    private $appuntamenti;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->appuntamenti = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
    public function addAppuntamenti(Appuntamento $app)
    {
        $this->appuntamenti[] = $app;
    }    

    public function getAppuntamenti()
    {
        return $this->appuntamenti;
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Appuntamento
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Clown", mappedBy="appuntamenti")
     */
    private $partecipanti;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->partecipanti = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
    public function addPartecipanti(Clown $partecipante)
    {
        $partecipante->addAppuntamenti($this);
        $this->partecipanti[] = $partecipante;
    }    

    public function getPartecipanti()
    {
        return $this->partecipanti;
    }
}
```

Then I create a form that allow to set the attendee (aka "partecipanti") of an Appuntamento.

```
namespace Clown\DiaryBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class PartecipantiType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')  
            ->add('partecipanti', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'ClownDiaryBundle:Clown',
                    'property' => 'drname',
                    'multiple'  => true,
                    'expanded'  => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'clown_diarybundle_partecipantitype';
    }
}
```

In the controller now I create the actions, one that shows the form, and one that update the entity.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/partecipanti", name="admin_appuntamento_partecipanti")
 * @Template()
 */
public function partecipantiAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ClownDiaryBundle:Appuntamento')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Appuntamento entity.');
    }

    $partecipantiForm = $this->createForm(new PartecipantiType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'partecipanti_form'   => $partecipantiForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/update_partecipanti", name="admin_appuntamento_update_partecipanti")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("ClownDiaryBundle:Appuntamento:partecipanti.html.twig")
 */
public function updatePartecipantiAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ClownDiaryBundle:Appuntamento')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Appuntamento entity.');
    }

    $partecipantiForm = $this->createForm(new PartecipantiType(), $entity);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $partecipantiForm->bindRequest($request);

    if ($partecipantiForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_appuntamento_show', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'partecipanti_form'   => $partecipantiForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

But when I get the post in the second action, and I try to persist the object, no association (between Clown and Appuntamento) has been created.
Am I forgotting something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should persist your entity through the owning side (the owning side is responsible for persisting). In your case the owning side is Clown, but you are trying persist through Appuntamento - that's why it doesn't persist.

Try change the owning side or persist through Clown entity.

You may want also read more about concept of owning / inversed sides:

- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html
- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html#picking-owning-and-inverse-side

Comment: It worked changing the Owning and Inverse side. Thanks to Cyprian!